# Editar campos en formulario con php

Tags: php, html, select, options

Tengo una tabla de tareas creada con php. Para editar las tareas, accedo a otra página en la que tengo el siguiente código:

```
    <td><label for="Tarea">Tarea</label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="Tarea" name="Tarea" value="<?php echo $rsEmp["Tarea"]; ?>" required >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="Importancia">Importancia</label></td>
<td>
<select name="Importancia" title="Importancia" value="<?php echo $rsEmp["Importancia"]; ?>" required >      
<option value="Crucial" id="Crucial" lang=es>Crucial</option>
<option value="Alta" id="Alta" lang=es>Alta</option>
<option value="Media" id="Media" lang=es>Media</option>
<option value="Baja" id="Baja" lang=es>Baja</option>
                                </select></td>
```

Esta tabla va a una hoja llamada editar que es donde está este código. El caso es que el campo "Tarea" lo recoge sin problemas pero el campo "Importancia" recoge el listado pero no tiene seleccionada por defecto la importancia de la tarea. Es decir, siempre aparece la importancia "Crucial" aunque la tarea tenga una importancia "Baja".

La conexión de la base de datos es la siguiente:

```css
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 000tareas WHERE ID = ".$idhc;
$queEmp = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$rsEmp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queEmp);
```

¿Alguien me puede indicar cómo puedo hacer que las celdas con campos desplegables tengan la opción seleccionada por defecto a la hora de editar la tarea?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Normalmente en los option se pone un `selected="selected"` a la que tiene que estar seleccionada. No veo que lo estés haciendo así que es complicado que se muestre :) Puedes poner algo como `<option value="Crucial" id="Crucial" lang="es" selected="<?php echo $rsEmp["Importancia"] == "Crucial" ? "selected":""; ?>">Crucial</option>`, eso debería funcionar. Personalmente haría una función auxiliar que devuelva el texto que necesitas directamente, pero vamos, ya lo implementas como quieras :)

Comment: Muchas gracias Benito, pero la opción SELECTED la puedo poner en uno de los campos, como por ejemplo "Crucial". Pero si en la base de datos la tarea es de una importancia "Baja", de nada me sirve que al editar la tarea me salga por defecto "Crucial". Lo que quiero es que una tarea que sea de importancia "Baja" aparezca por defecto con ese valor. Y si otra tarea tiene importancia "Media", aparezca por defecto con el valor "Media".

Comment: A ver... obviamente en mi ejemplo usé una única opción, tendrás que poner ese `if` en todas las demás, cada una con su valor... te he dado una idea, de hecho, puedes literalmente copiar y pegar el código y lo único que tienes que cambiar es el valor `"Crucial"` por el que corresponda en los demás casos... OBVIAMENTE, ese código no sirve de nada ponerlo en una única opción, tal como has dicho... lo que no sé es qué te impide ponerlo en **las demás opciones cada una con su correspondiente valor en el if!** El caso es que el que coincida con el valor de la BD llevará `SELECTED` y los demás no.

Answer (score 1):

El formato para establecer un campo por defecto en un select es :

```html
<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
<select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Ahora si lo que necesitas es que ese valor `selected` lo puedas manejar a través de PHP, entonces puedes hacer un echo a través de un switch o asignando valores a un array, y leyendo una variable desde tu base de datos en donde obtendrías la prioridad mediante un valor numérico entonces solo bastaría crear ese select.

```php
<td><label for="Tarea">Tarea</label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="Tarea" name="Tarea" value="<?php echo $rsEmp["Tarea"]; ?>" required >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="Importancia">Importancia</label></td>
<td>
    <select name="Importancia" id="Importancia">
        <?php
            $importancia = 3; // valor obtenido de la base de datos

            $opciones = array(
                1 => 'Crucial',
                2 => 'Alta',
                3 => 'Media',
                4 => 'Baja'
            );

            foreach ($opciones as $valor => $texto) {
                $selected = ($valor == $importancia) ? 'selected' : '';
                echo "<option value='$valor' $selected>$texto</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>


</td>
```

Comment: Meter un switch duplicando todas las opciones es una barbaridad. Cuando quieras añadir una opción más que haces, añadirla a todos los case del switch?? Basta con meter un if dentro de la propia `option` y utilizar el valor como condición para ponerlo

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, se puede mejorar sin duda.